# cucumber how to pass variables between testrunnner and step definition class

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(<configuration>) 
public Class TestRunner{}

public Class StepDefinitions{}

public Class SomeClass{}
```

Is there a way to pass object of type SomeClass from TestRunner to StepDefintions? The reason behind this requirement is to have a single object of someClass object for all scenarios.

Comment: How about using a singelton object?

Answer (score 0):

The way to share information between steps in different step classes in Cucumber-JVM is to use dependency injection.

Cucumber has bindings to many different dependency injection frameworks. One of them is PicoContainer. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) a while back describing how it can be used.